# Is Distributed SQL Query on Hazelcast for IMap<String, Set< Object>> possible?

Tags: java, sql, hazelcast

I have a `IMap<String, Set<Contact>>` where Contact is defined as

```
public Class Contact {
    private String name;
    private String email;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Now, is it possible to query for a parameter through all the contacts in the HazelCast Instance? Example:

```
Set<Contact> contacts = (Set<Contact>) map.values(new SqlPredicate("email LIKE 'john%' "));
```

I have seen examples where the above query is made for a `IMap<String, Object>` and not for `IMap<String, Set<Object>>`.

Is it possible to make such a query?

Answer (score 0):

No it is not. IT can be possible if query is supported for multimap.
https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/593

Comment: Thought so. Any idea why query on multimap isn't supported? Is it difficult to implement? Or are there other issues related to it